# Input value doesn't display in WooCommerce city field

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce for my shop.
I had to changed city field dropdown to input field, so I changed it by some plugin.
Now the field is text type `input type="text"` as i wish but the value is not displaying in field. It's just showing placeholder.
I attached an image from Inspect Element of google chrome.

**Image**
[image]

As you see, in the left side city field is not displaying value but in the right side (Source Code), value is set as **New York**. As I said it's just showing placeholder.

If anyone can help me please let me know about solution.
Thank you all.

Comment: Disable javascript and style then see what is going on. there should be either javascript code or css that is clearing the value

Comment: when i disabled javascript it's showing field as  a dropdown!! <select name="billing_city" id="billing_city" class="state_select wcfe-input-field" autocomplete="address-level2" placeholder="select a city"></select>